# Detect and identify GUI components from Java

Tags: java, user-interface, resources

I need to create a Java application that can detect any GUI component of an application on Windows or Linux.  For example, you have a Firefox browser running and I want to have a list of interactive components (such as buttons, menus) and possibly drive Firefox with my program (sort of like a remote controller).  Do the OSes provide some capabilities that enable this?

I remember from a long time ago when I did some automated software testing, the testing software could tell each GUI component of any application on Windows.  I've looked around and found ResourceHacker (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/rh_shot.html) and it's somewhat similar.

Is this possible through Java?  If not, what language might be suitable? Any opensource solutions out there?

Any pointer/advice would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: *"Is this possible through Java?"*  I'd imagine not short of a load of native code.